# ¿Cómo utilizar un objeto JSON guardado en el localStorage?

Tags: javascript, json

me encuentro estudiando sobre el tema de localStorage y bueno he aprendido a guardar objetos en formato JSON y como obtenerlos después, pero tengo curiosidad en conocer como se puede utilizar el "valor" del objeto guardado ya que quisiera agregar contenido para después volverlo a guardar.

Esto es lo que tengo en una función de javascript:

```
let claveAux = {'aux':'PRODUCTOS/IMPRESORAS/'};
   localStorage.setItem('claveAux', JSON.stringify(claveAux));
```

luego en otro javscript quiero obtener el valor del objeto guardado para poder modificarlo pero de lo que he visto hasta el momento solamente es como obtenerlo del localStorage y parsearlo para poder verlo en consola mediante el siguiente código:

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('claveAux');
   console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

en consola lo veo tal y como lo definí pero quisiera poder grabar solo la parte del valor en una variable para modificarla.

[image: obtención del objeto]

y lo que yo quisiera es solo obtener el "PRODUCTOS/IMPRESORAS/" para agregarle otra palabra según la operación que se elija.

**¿Cómo puedo obtener solo esta cadena? Debo poner la "key" del objeto al momento que se está parseando ej:

```
JSON.parse(retrievedObject['aux']);
```

lo siguiente es un ejemplo de la instrucción de lo que quiero realizar con la cadena.

```
let clave = retrievedObject+cl+"/info.json";
```

Comment: Tendrías que hacer así: `JSON.parse(retrievedObject)['aux'];` Porque antes de parsearlo es un String. Aunque creo que si no llamas `JSON.stringify` cuando lo almacenás debería funcionar como querés.

Answer (score 0):

podrias guardar el json en otra variable y acceder a cada propiedad del json:

```
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('claveAux');
    var vFinal = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

    console.log(vFinal.aux)
```